# print json object to string format

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails-3

Iam trying print json object to string format.

(Actually i got these data value from ruby code
 `var data = '<%=[@pro {|c| {x:c.x, y:c.y}}].to_json%>'`)

while printing the data variable i got values containing `&quot` instead of `'`

```
var data=[[{&quot;x&quot;:1,&quot;y&quot;:0}]]
```

I want to get the values in the format `var data="[[{ 'x': '1', 'y': '0' }]]";`

while removing `&quot;` using the code `var dataset=JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));` got in the following format.

var dataset =[[{"x":1,"y":0}]]

i want to print the values like `[[{ 'x': '1', 'y': '0' }]]`.How it is possible.

Comment: Are you sure it's ruby related? May be it's ruby-on-rails related?

Comment: yes ruby on rails related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using only 2 variables, than you can simple do like that:

```
var data = [[{'x': '<%= @pro.x %>', 'y': '<%= @pro.y %>'}]];
```

And no need to use `to_json` method.

If you are want to stringify many values than this code works like a charm:

```
<% array = [[{'x' => 1, 'y' => 1}], [{'x' => 2, 'y' => 2}], [{'x' => 3, 'y' => 3}]] %>
<%= array.to_json %>
```

And he outputs:

```
[[{"x":1,"y":1}],[{"x":2,"y":2}],[{"x":3,"y":3}]]
```

If you need to send json by request in your controller use:

```
def send_json_array
    array = [[{'x' => 1, 'y' => 1}], [{'x' => 2, 'y' => 2}], [{'x' => 3, 'y' => 3}]]
    response.headers['Content-type'] = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    render :text => array.to_json
end
```

Answer (score -3):

JSON.stringify converts an object to its json format.

```
var dataset =[[{"x":1,"y":0}]]
var JsonData = JSON.stringify(dataset);
```